# I don't know how to continue with this program of getting last names from a list of strings and printing them out in python

Tags: python

I am doing a homework assignment where it wants me to print out the last names from a list of names. It also says I only need 2-3 extra lines of code max. How would I do this?

This is a lesson on lists and I have always had trouble with indexing lists but this takes my mind beyond what I can think.

Here is my code with the list they provided:

```py
names = [
    "Maya Angelou",
    "Chimamanda Ngozi Adichie",
    "Tobias Wolff",
    "Sherman Alexie",
    "Aziz Ansari"
]

# Your code here...
name = [names[i].split() for i in range(len(names))]
print(name)
```

The expected result is:

['Angelou', 'Adichie', 'Wolff', 'Alexie', 'Ansari']

My result:

[['Maya', 'Angelou'], ['Chimamanda', 'Ngozi', 'Adichie'], ['Tobias', 'Wolff'], ['Sherman', 'Alexie'], ['Aziz', 'Ansari']]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use    `print([i[-1] for i in name])` 
instead of `print(name)`

This indeed prints `['Angelou', 'Adichie', 'Wolff', 'Alexie', 'Ansari']`

Answer (score 0):

Your code is completely fine you just need to take the second variable after you split the name -

```
names = [my_names[i].split()[1:] for i in range(len(my_names))]
```

and add a line to join the names if there are two last names or so.

All the code:

```
my_names = [
    "Maya Angelou",
    "Chimamanda Ngozi Adichie",
    "Tobias Wolff",
    "Sherman Alexie",
    "Aziz Ansari"
]

# Your code here...
names = [my_names[i].split()[1:] for i in range(len(my_names))]
fixed_names = [' '.join(name) for name in names]
print(fixed_names)
```

Comment: This code will not work for the second name: "Chimamanda Ngozi Adichie".

Answer (score 0):

```
names = [
    "Maya Angelou",
    "Chimamanda Ngozi Adichie",
    "Tobias Wolff",
    "Sherman Alexie",
    "Aziz Ansari"
]

for current_name in names:
    print(current_name.split()[-1])
```

Output:

```
Angelou
Adichie
Wolff
Alexie
Ansari
```

For every name in your list of names, take the current name, split it on whitespace, and print the last element of the resulting list.

If they really want the output to look like a list, you can change it into a list comprehension:

```
names = [
    "Maya Angelou",
    "Chimamanda Ngozi Adichie",
    "Tobias Wolff",
    "Sherman Alexie",
    "Aziz Ansari"
]

last_names = [current_name.split()[-1] for current_name in names]
print(last_names)
```

Output:

```
['Angelou', 'Adichie', 'Wolff', 'Alexie', 'Ansari']
```